# C# Error Help - "ExecuteNonQuery: CommandText property has not been initialized "

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am having trouble calling my nonquery. When I run this I get the following error- "ExecuteNonQuery: CommandText property has not been initialized"

```
        //delete from the database
        OdbcCommand cmdCommand = new OdbcCommand(tSQL, Global.gADOConnection);
        tSQL = "Delete from SEARCH_CRITERIA where CRITERIA_ID = " + iCriteriaID;
        Global.gADOConnection.Open();
        cmdCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Global.gADOConnection.Close();
```

I am not sure why I continue to get this error. Can anyone help me please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting the value of `tSQL` *after* you've passed it into the `OdbcCommand` constructor. I suspect that's not what you wanted. Try:

```
string tSQL = "Delete from SEARCH_CRITERIA where CRITERIA_ID = " + iCriteriaID;
using (OdbcCommand cmdCommand = new OdbcCommand(tSQL, Global.gADOConnection))
{
    Global.gADOConnection.Open();
    cmdCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Global.gADOConnection.Close();
}
```

However:

- I'd strongly advise you to use parameterized SQL instead of embedding the value inside the SQL itself
- Note how I'm using a `using` statement to dispose the command at the end
- I'd also strongly advise you *not* to use a global variable for the database connection. Create a new connection each time you need a database operation, and dispose of it at the end:

  ```
   using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(...))
   {
       connection.Open();
       using (OdbcCommand command = ...)
       {
           command.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
   }
  ```

  Let the connection pool handle making that efficient in terms of the underlying network connections.

Answer (score 1):

The tSQL needs to go in front of the cmdCommand:

```
tSQL = "Delete from SEARCH_CRITERIA where CRITERIA_ID = " + iCriteriaID;
OdbcCommand cmdCommand = new OdbcCommand(tSQL, Global.gADOConnection);
```

You should really use parameters to avoid sql injection.

```
tSQL = "Delete from SEARCH_CRITERIA where CRITERIA_ID = @CriteriaID";
OdbcCommand cmdCommand = new OdbcCommand(tSQL, Global.gADOConnection);
cmdCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CriteriaID", iCriteriaID);
```

The next thing to consider is `using` brackets to automatically close your resources.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the Command with `null` command text. Try assigning tSQL before creating the command.

```
var tSQL = "Delete from SEARCH_CRITERIA where CRITERIA_ID = " + iCriteriaID;
OdbcCommand cmdCommand = new OdbcCommand(tSQL, Global.gADOConnection);
Global.gADOConnection.Open();
cmdCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
Global.gADOConnection.Close();
```

Comment: I actually still got the error when doing that but tried - OdbcCommand cmdCommand = new OdbcCommand("Delete from SEARCH_CRITERIA where CRITERIA_ID = " + iCriteriaID, Global.gADOConnection);
Global.gADOConnection.Open();
cmdCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
Global.gADOConnection.Close();

This came back without errors. Thanks for the help.